# MarkerClusterGroup and filters with Mapbox

Tags: mapbox

I tried to implement the code suggested in this question:

[Trouble using Leafletjs MarkerClusterGroup and filters with Mapbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619883/trouble-using-leafletjs-markerclustergroup-and-filters-with-mapbox)

I have this error popping up in firebug when I try to implement the code above:
this._geojson.features is undefined

Would someone have a working example to share?

Thanks!

Comment: This needs much more detail. What code in specific are you using, and with what data?

Comment: My code is [here](https://github.com/Edouard-Legoupil/qips-project/blob/gh-pages/index3.html).Thanks!

Comment: That's a very odd way to filter marker clusters: I'd recommend not doing that, or storing ._geojson at all, and instead just filtering the JavaScript array totally externally to the markercluster, just calling clearLayers and addData when complete.