# Update GeoJSON SQL query when a select box changes - L.markerClusterGroup(); Causing Error

Tags: jquery, sql, leaflet, geojson

I am trying to change the SQL query when a select box changes.  It's working, but instead of clearing out what is currently there it's just resubmitting the same query and adding it to the existing one. So if I have 440 results and select an option I now get 880 results.

I thought that `map.removeLayer (geojson);` would take care of that but I think I am missing something.

```
<select id="dropdown_selector">
    <option value="Agricultural">Agricultural</option>
    <option value="Property">Property</option>
    <option value="VisualImpact">Visual Impact</option>
    <option value="Safety">Safety</option>
    <option value="Vegetation">Vegetation</option>
</select>


    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
      var geojson = null;  
      var sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM cartoDBdatabase";

  // CALL THE CARTODB SQL API HERE IN URL FORMAT
  function setViewer(){
      if(map.hasLayer(geojson)){
        map.removeLayer(geojson);
      };

      $.getJSON("https://username.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?format=GeoJSON&q="+sqlQuery, function(data, latlng) {
        geojson = L.geoJson(data, {
        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
            return L.marker(latlng, {
              icon: L.icon({
                iconSize: [27, 27],
                iconAnchor: [13, 27],
                popupAnchor:  [1, -24], 
                iconUrl: 'images/commentMarker.png'
              })
            })
          },
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {          
        // ADD A POPUP WITH SOME INFO
        layer.bindPopup("<h2>" + feature.properties.name + "</h2><hr><p><b>Comment:</b> " + feature.properties.description + "</p><p><b>User Address:</b> " + feature.properties.profile_address +"</p><p><b>User Address:</b> " + feature.properties.profile_address +"</p>" );

      }
    });
    markers.removeLayer(geojson);
    markers.addLayer(geojson);
    markers.addTo(map);

           $('#dropdown_selector').change(function(){
                 var commentType = $(this).val();
                 sqlQuery: "SELECT * FROM cartoDBdatabase WHERE comment_type ILIKE '%"+commentType+"%'";
                setViewer();
          });
  });
  }

  setViewer();
```

I have narrowed it down to the leaflet plugin L.markerClusterGroup();, but I have no idea how to fix this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:
I have moved markers.addTo(map); and deleted markers.addLayer(geojson); and markers.removeLayer(geojson); as suggested. But then no markers were showing up. So I added markers.addLayer(geojson); back in and it's working better now, but when you select another value to update, it still just adds it onto the previous markers shown, instead of removing the previous values.

```
    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
    var markers2 = L.markerClusterGroup();
    markers.addTo(map);
    markers2.addTo(map);

    var geojson = null;  
    var geojson2 = null;  

   $('#dropdown_selector').change(function(){  
            if(map.hasLayer(geojson2)){
                geojson2.clearLayers(); //it would remove all features
                markers2.clearLayers(); //it would remove any geojson features added before
            };
            commentType = $(this).val();               
            setViewerFilter();
   });


 function setViewer(){  
        if(map.hasLayer(geojson)){
            geojson.clearLayers(); //it would remove all features
            markers.clearLayers(); //it would remove any geojson features added before
        };
        if(map.hasLayer(geojson2)){
            geojson2.clearLayers(); //it would remove all features
            markers2.clearLayers(); //it would remove any geojson features added before
        };

      $.getJSON("https://username.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?format=GeoJSON&q=SELECT * FROM cartoDBdatabase", function(data, latlng) {
       geojson = L.geoJson(data, {
        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
            return L.marker(latlng, {
              icon: L.icon({
                iconSize: [27, 27],
                iconAnchor: [13, 27],
                popupAnchor:  [1, -24], 
                iconUrl: 'images/commentMarker.png'
              })
            })
          },
      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {          
        // ADD A POPUP WITH SOME INFO
        layer.bindPopup("<h2>" + feature.properties.name + "</h2><hr><p><b>Comment:</b> " + feature.properties.description + "</p><p><b>User Address:</b> " + feature.properties.profile_address +"</p><p><b>Comment Address:</b> " + feature.properties.comment_address +"</p><p><b>Comment Type:</b> " + feature.properties.comment_type +"</p><p><b>Comment Type Other:</b> " + feature.properties.comment_type_other +"</p><p><b>Email:</b> " + feature.properties.email_address +"</p><p><b>Parcel ID:</b> " + feature.properties.parcel_id +"</p><p><b>User Type:</b> " + feature.properties.user_type +"</p><p><b>User Type Other:</b> " + feature.properties.user_type_other +"</p>" );

      }
    });
    markers.addLayer(geojson);
  });
  }

  function setViewerFilter(){  
        geojson.clearLayers(); //it would remove all features
        markers.clearLayers(); //it would remove any geojson features added before
    if(map.hasLayer(geojson2)){
        geojson2.clearLayers(); //it would remove all features
        markers2.clearLayers(); //it would remove any geojson features added before
    };
      $.getJSON("https://username.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql?format=GeoJSON&q=SELECT * FROM cartoDBdatabaseWHERE comment_type LIKE '"+commentType+"'", function(data, latlng) {
       geojson2 = L.geoJson(data, {
        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
            return L.marker(latlng, {
              icon: L.icon({
                iconSize: [27, 27],
                iconAnchor: [13, 27],
                popupAnchor:  [1, -24], 
                iconUrl: 'images/commentMarker.png'
              })
            })
          },

      onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {          
        // ADD A POPUP WITH SOME INFO
        layer.bindPopup("<h2>" + feature.properties.name + "</h2><hr><p><b>Comment:</b> " + feature.properties.description + "</p><p><b>User Address:</b> " + feature.properties.profile_address +"</p><p><b>Comment Address:</b> " + feature.properties.comment_address +"</p><p><b>Comment Type:</b> " + feature.properties.comment_type +"</p><p><b>Comment Type Other:</b> " + feature.properties.comment_type_other +"</p><p><b>Email:</b> " + feature.properties.email_address +"</p><p><b>Parcel ID:</b> " + feature.properties.parcel_id +"</p><p><b>User Type:</b> " + feature.properties.user_type +"</p><p><b>User Type Other:</b> " + feature.properties.user_type_other +"</p>" );

      }
    });
    markers2.addLayer(geojson2);
  });
  }

  setViewer();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want the code

```
markers.removeLayer(geojson);
markers.addLayer(geojson);
```

To remove the old geojson layer, and add the new one. But this code runs *after* you have reassigned the `geojson` variable to the new value, so it's just removing & re-adding the new layer.

To fix this, you would run `markers.removelayer(geojson)` *before* reassigning the value of the `geojson` variable.

Comment: Yes this is what I have tried to do, but this is not working - just keeps the previous markers and adds more on top of them.

Comment: I have found a solution for the Mapbox version of this, link below, which seems to address the issue I am having: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619883/trouble-using-leafletjs-markerclustergroup-and-filters-with-mapbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17619883/trouble-using-leafletjs-markerclustergroup-and-filters-with-mapbox) however, I don't know how to convert this code into something usable for my situation....

Comment: just looking at this again. Maybe I haven't tried running markers.removeLayer(geojson) before the geojson variable.... I tried a couple of ways, but it's removing too soon and not adding it to the map at all. Any chance you could show an example?

Answer (score 0):

When you're using `map.hasLayer(geojson)`, modify this like below

```
if(map.hasLayer(geojson)){
    geojson.clearLayers(); //it would remove all features
    markers.clearLayers(); //it would remove any geojson features added before
};
```

Also modify these three lines which you have after `$.getJSON`

```
//remove below two lines
markers.removeLayer(geojson); //remove this line
markers.addLayer(geojson); //remove this line

//move this line from here
markers.addTo(map); //need to move this line from here and add up after L.markerClusterGroup();
```

When you're initiating `L.markerClusterGroup()`, add it to map after it as well

```
var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();
markers.addTo(map); // add cluster object to map, after initializing
```

Comment: (See above UPDATE) I have moved markers.addTo(map); and deleted markers.addLayer(geojson); and markers.removeLayer(geojson); as you suggested, but then no markers were showing up. So I added markers.addLayer(geojson); back in and it's working better now but still not solved... When you select another value to update, it still just adds it onto the previous markers shown, instead of removing the previous values.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your work, so I can look what is creating issue?